# how to ASP VB format datetime - remove seconds

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, datetime-format

I am using the code like

```
dateadd("n",FTimeZoneDifference,theTime)
```

Which returns me the date time as `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss ttt` (ttt is for AM or PM)

I want to remove seconds only, is it possible?

Comment: please specify ASP.net or classic ASP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own string, as classic ASP has no built in functions for what you need:

```
myDate = dateadd("n", FTimeZoneDifference, theTime)
myString = Month(myDate) & "/" & Day(myDate) & "/" & Year(myDate) & " " ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to get AM PM only (directly- withough looking at hour value)?

Comment: @Umer I fear no but getting it is as easy as `strAmPm = "AM" : If Hour(myDate)>12 Then strAmPm="PM"` (one single line)

Answer (score 2):

You probably are going to have to roll your own. You can do like [Shadow Wizard shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857906/how-to-asp-vb-format-datetime-remove-seconds/5862263#5862263), or an alternate version like this:

```
myDate = dateadd("n", FTimeZoneDifference, theTime)
myString = FormatDateTime(myDate,vbShortDate) & " " & FormatDateTime(myDate,vbShortTime)
```

The benefit to Shadow Wizard's is you have more control over the output, where this version is more dependent on the system's setting for short date and short time.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the useful FormatDateTime, here is link to its official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s(v=vs.85).aspx :)